# system() call .exe on Window 7 using C++ [Permission Issue]

Tags: c++, windows

I'm a beginner to C++ programmer and to Stackoverflow

I'm trying to use `system()` to call an .exe from my program to convert RTF to plain text by using:

```
system("converter.exe convert doc.doc > doc.txt")
```

from my understanding of `system()` ==>> `system("program.exe arg1")`.
When I compile this code it brings up the converter.exe but it does not give me the output (.txt).
I came to the conclusion that Visual Studio 2010 uses non-administrative CMD to open this .exe where the program just pop up for 1 sec and disappears (also I need to press "ok" before executing).

Any suggestions how to run `system()` with administrator permission ?

PS: I tried changing the "run as administrator" on the .exe but it appears that the system doesn't allow me to change anything.

Comment: User Access Control doesn't work like that. It either fails or succeeds for starting the process. It doesn't give you 1 second. Most probably the current directory of the process is not what you think it is.

Comment: Maybe the current directory don't give you permission to write `doc.txt` inside it.

Comment: **1**.Why do you need admin privileges for text conversion? It doesn't sound right.  **2**.Start your program from a console, not from VS, and see what happens.  **3**.Try giving full path instead of just "doc.txt". Could be the current directory at the time of `system()` isn't what you expect, and the file just ends up somewhere you don't look for it.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need admin privileges, consider using [runas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc772672.aspx):

> system("runas /user:foo \"converter.exe convert doc.doc > doc.txt\"")